# Searching for keywords in HTML files stored in the same directory

Tags: javascript, php

How to create a search engine searching for keywords in HTML files stored in the same directory (or in the same domain) with Javascript or PHP ? It would be appreciated if any hints are given.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too broad.  The rule of thumb here is "if you can imagine a book being written to answer this question, it's too broad for Stack Exchange."  If you come to specific problems once you've started your project, we might be able to help you with those.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the HTML-file contents in a variable with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Next check the variable content for the keyword with [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) which will return the position of the first character of the found keyword in the string.